# DataGridViewColumnCollection resetting for unknown reason

Tags: c#, winforms

I've set up a `DataGridViewColumnCollection` as follows:

```
private DataGridViewColumnCollection columns;

    private void RemoveStaffFromList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        columns = dataGridViewStaff.Columns;
        MessageBox.Show(columns.Count.ToString());
        dataGridViewStaff.DataSource = null;
        MessageBox.Show(columns.Count.ToString());
    }
```

MessageBox 1 returns "4", MessageBox 2 returns "0", so `columns` obviously resets when I nullify the DataSource. But why? Shouldn't `columns` be treated as a variable separate from `dataGridViewStaff` and hence be unaffected by the DataSource change?

Comment: Nope.  Using a DataSource, both the data and the columns and types come from that DataSource.   Not sure what you are doing with `DataGridViewColumnCollection` but it looks like you are printing the column count from 2 different things

Answer (score 1):

Because your `columns` variable simply points to the same memory location as `dataGridViewStaff.Columns` so when you set datasource to `null` the `columns` becomes empty hence the 0.

Comment: So then, is there a way I can force it to store the value in a separate memory location?

Comment: @PeterWritesCode with a lot of hassle I suppose, you would need to create a brand new `DataGridView` `var columns = new DataGridViewColumnCollection(new DataGridView());` and then copy the columns one by one, but to be honest, I'd advise strongly against it because there is a reason why `DataGridView` doesn't have such cloning  methods in built.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to assign false to [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether columns are created
>   automatically when the DataSource or DataMember properties are set.

Columns are automatically generated when this property is set to true and the DataSource or DataMember properties are set or changed.